# Select Time property from Test-Connection in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hello I found this script online below and I am trying to add time as a output but it seems like I cannot select time from test-connection command. I can select for address but not time?

```
#selecting for address works
Test-Connection -computername 10.15.31.1 | select Address

#selecting for time does not work
Test-Connection -computername 10.15.31.1 | select Time


#You can see below what I am trying to achieve

 $output=foreach ($name in $names) {
 [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
    Source= $ipaddress
    Destination = $name
  #  Time=Test-Connection -computername 10.15.31.1 | select Time 
    Ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Quiet -Count 1 
  }
}
```

Comment: the `-Quiet` means that the cmdlet ONLY returns a boolean. so there won't be anything there beyond a `False/True` ... [*grin*]

Comment: thats fine because thats exactly what i want. but how can i select time property only? or add the time property part

Comment: there IS NOTHING ELSE. [*grin*] there is no time property ... only the boolean all by itself. that is the entire reason for the `-Quiet` parameter of that cmdlet. if you want the time info ... remove the `-Quiet` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So lets figure this out.

```
(Test-Connection -computername 8.8.8.8 -Count 1) | select *
```

Will bring back

```
PSComputerName                 : Test-Computer
IPV4Address                    : 8.8.4.4
IPV6Address                    : 
__GENUS                        : 2
__CLASS                        : Win32_PingStatus
__SUPERCLASS                   : 
__DYNASTY                      : Win32_PingStatus
__RELPATH                      : Win32_PingStatus.Address="8.8.8.8",BufferSize=32,NoFragmentation=FALSE,RecordRoute=0,ResolveAddressNames=FALSE,SourceRoute="",SourceRouteType
                                 =0,Timeout=4000,TimestampRoute=0,TimeToLive=80,TypeofService=0
__PROPERTY_COUNT               : 24
__DERIVATION                   : {}
__SERVER                       : Test-Computer
__NAMESPACE                    : root\cimv2
__PATH                         : \\Test-Computer\root\cimv2:Win32_PingStatus.Address="8.8.8.8",BufferSize=32,NoFragmentation=FALSE,RecordRoute=0,ResolveAddressNames=FALSE,Source
                                 Route="",SourceRouteType=0,Timeout=4000,TimestampRoute=0,TimeToLive=80,TypeofService=0
Address                        : 8.8.8.8
BufferSize                     : 32
NoFragmentation                : False
PrimaryAddressResolutionStatus : 0
ProtocolAddress                : 8.8.8.8
ProtocolAddressResolved        : 
RecordRoute                    : 0
ReplyInconsistency             : False
ReplySize                      : 32
ResolveAddressNames            : False
ResponseTime                   : 16
ResponseTimeToLive             : 54
RouteRecord                    : 
RouteRecordResolved            : 
SourceRoute                    : 
SourceRouteType                : 0
StatusCode                     : 0
Timeout                        : 4000
TimeStampRecord                : 
TimeStampRecordAddress         : 
TimeStampRecordAddressResolved : 
TimestampRoute                 : 0
TimeToLive                     : 80
TypeofService                  : 0
Scope                          : System.Management.ManagementScope
Path                           : \\Test-Computer\root\cimv2:Win32_PingStatus.Address="8.8.8.8",BufferSize=32,NoFragmentation=false,RecordRoute=0,ResolveAddressNames=false,Source
                                 Route="",SourceRouteType=0,Timeout=4000,TimestampRoute=0,TimeToLive=80,TypeofService=0
Options                        : System.Management.ObjectGetOptions
ClassPath                      : \\Test-Computer\root\cimv2:Win32_PingStatus
Properties                     : {Address, BufferSize, NoFragmentation, PrimaryAddressResolutionStatus...}
SystemProperties               : {__GENUS, __CLASS, __SUPERCLASS, __DYNASTY...}
Qualifiers                     : {dynamic, provider}
Site                           : 
Container                      :
```

We can see that you are looking for ResponseTime

```
Test-Connection -computername 8.8.8.8 | select ResponseTime
```

Will Return

```
ResponseTime
------------
          18
          18
          15
          13
```

Now `Test-Connection -computername 8.8.8.8 -Quiet`
Will only return a `$true` or `$false` so make sure you **DO NOT** use that if you are trying to get more detailed information.

Comment: If This does what you are looking for. Make sure to mark it as correct.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I was looking for !! Thank again ArcSet!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a quick pinglog or something, you can try something like this:

```
Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -Count 1 | Select-Object @{n='Date';e={Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"}},@{n='Timestamp';e={Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"}},Address,ResponseTime | Export-Csv -Path c:\output.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

That's a quick-n-dirty way to do periodic checks.